# prove/disprove if each two in $n$ operators can be diagonalizable simultaneously then all can be diagonalizable simultaneously

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, diagonalization

I have an idea that for $n$ diagonalizable operators $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n \in \ell(V)$. if each $A_i, A_j$ can be diagonalizable simultaneously then all of them can be diagonalizable simultaneously.

if it is true then we can prove that for every permutation the answer of  $A_{i_1}A_{i_2}...A_{i_n}$ is the same **iff** they are diagonalizable simultaneously.

can you prove or disprove that?

Comment: If $A_i$ and $A_j$ are simultaneously diagonalisable, then they commute: $A_iA_j=A_jA_i$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown look at the "iff" part.

Comment: Are we talking about bounded operators on a Hilbert space? And by diagonalizable, do you mean unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator?